# Can SAS support numeric that is longer than 16 digits?

Tags: sas, numeric

I have a requirement set whereby some of the SAS numeric columns must be able to store numeric value that is more than 16 digits. For example:
123,456,789,123,456,789,123,123.9996

It is actually 24.4 by looking at that.

I've studied a few pages such as :
http://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/unixc/z0344718.htm
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm
[http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/win/numvar.htm#:~:text=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20variables,can%20be%20is%20160%20bytes](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/win/numvar.htm#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20variables,can%20be%20is%20160%20bytes).

It seems to me that the maximum numeric length that SAS support is 8 bytes which can only support 16 digits whole number. Is there a way to achieve numeric value that is "24.4" like the above example?

Comment: No.  Proc FedSQL will let you work with remote data base hosts that have BigInt types.  Proc DS2 also supports INT64 types. The default SAS library engine does not support bigint.

Comment: Do you just need to store the values? Or do you also need to do arithmetic with this values?  If you just want to store them then store them as character strings.

Comment: Those are really old references (20 years+), search the site `documentation.sas.com` to get the most recent one. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm

Comment: did you get an answer for your question yet ? Native SAS would not handle a number that large. Can you explain what the number is conceptually ? If I understood what it is and what you're doing with it maybe I could figure out a work-around. the number you are using in your example is roughly the number of cells in all human bodies currently on the planet Earth.